# How to load log4j2.properties file from outside the classpath programatically?

Tags: log4j2

How to load the different log4j2.properties file from outside the classpath after it is initialized with another properties file from classpath.I have tried the below code

```
Configurator.initialize(null, "G:/log4j2.properties");
final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(LoggingSetupService.class.getName());
LOGGER.debug(logMessage);
```

The new log4j2.properties file has different filepath for creating the log file but the log file is created with the filepath from the classpath properties file

Comment: can you post your both `log4j2` configuration files because similar code is working fine at my end.

Comment: FYI, log file will get created in `classpath` properties file location also because that is first configuration file loaded. Once, you explicitly initialize it using external configuration file, after that, logs will go in that configuration file.